# Javascript Regular Expression for International Phone Number

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regular expression isn't working for international phone numbers that can allow up to 15 digits:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-().\s]{10,15}$
```

What needs to be adjusted?

Comment: And you are sure that "international phone numbers" are not longer than 15 digits?

Comment: I am just following the instructions of my client.

Comment: Then what are the rules that your client has instructed you to follow?

Comment: what that {10,15} means anyway?
is that minimum is 10 digit and max is 15 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a backslash:

```
var unrealisticPhoneNumberRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-().\s]{10,15}$/;
```

Now it's still not very useful because you allow an arbitrary number of punctuation characters too.  Really, validating a phone number like this — especially if you want it to really work for *all possible* international phone numbers — is probably a hopeless task.  I suggest you go with what @BalusC suggests.

Answer (score 11):

You may find the following regex more useful, it basically first strips all valid special characters which an [international phone number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan) can contain (spaces, parens, `+`, `-`, `.`, `ext`) and then counts if there are at least 7 digits (minimum length for a valid local number).

```
function isValidPhonenumber(value) {
    return (/^\d{7,}$/).test(value.replace(/[\s()+\-\.]|ext/gi, ''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) and [Is there a standard for storing normalized phone numbers in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925/is-there-a-standard-for-storing-normalized-phone-numbers-in-a-database#41982)

Answer (score 0):

> and then counts if there are at least 7 digits (minimum length for a valid local number).

The shortest local numbers anywhere in the world are only two or three digits long.

There are many countries without area codes.

There are several well-known places with a 3 digit country code and 4 digit local numbers.

It may be prudent to drop your limit to 6 or 5; just in case.