# Javascript RegEx for Global phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I was browsing through the internet to find a proper javascript regular expression for phone numbers but the ones I find are not the ones I need.

The acceptable phone number type for my case would have to match the following rules:

- May start with `+` or `0-9`
- all rest string is allowed to have only `0-9`, `-` and space (preferably only 1 space between numbers)

I tried so far this: `/^\+[\-\d\s]/` but I am not getting the proper result. I've tried to read  some tutorials but I am very new to this and it seems I am missing something.

An acceptable phone number for example would be: +30 6995 4488551 (spaces allowed) or 0030 6995 4488551 etc.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Dashs, spaces, hyphens, etc are formatting. Don't allow or reject them - ignore them when you test.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147614/javascript-regular-expression-for-international-phone-number[/link]

Comment: Thank you for the replies but those answers of that topic are not what I need, because in the answers they just strip the characters they don't want and validate the rest. I don't think that's a good way of dealing with it. I want for the user to input correct strings. For example, the users cannot input `+` wherever they want, but only at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches anything that starts with a `+` followed by a single `-`, digit or whitespace character. So you will match for example:

- +4qwertzuiopasdfghjkl
- +-asdfasdfasdfasdf

I suggest you to look at the examples and tutorials on http://www.regular-expressions.info/. As for your telephone numbers a better regex would be:

```
/^\+?[\d -]+$/
```

This would match all valid numbers but also invalid constructions like `+---------` or simply `+` with a trailing space. If you want to be really close to denying a lot of invalid combinations I would suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation), but as you can see the regexes get messy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to migg's answer -- you could add more filters after the regex test that could, for example, make sure there are at least a minimum number of digits in the expression, or what have you.
e.g.,

```
 if !(phone_number.match(/\d/g).length == 9) inValidate()
```