# Escape special characters from the database - MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, escaping

Hi guys I need to search for a data in the database like 123.456.789
how can I search it even if I only entered 123456789 ?
I need to escape the special characters from the database so that even if i search for 123456789 it can also display values like 123.456.789.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients 
WHERE REPLACE(phone, '.', '') LIKE ".$searchtext."
```

... where `searchtext` is the number im looking for. It should return all values that match regardless of whatever special characters are present.

Comment: Please share your query.

Comment: @user868766 here is my query `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REPLACE(phone, '.', '') LIKE ".$searchtext."` where searchtext is the number im looking for. It should return all values that match regardless of whatever special characters are present.

Comment: It's the first time I see regular dot considered a special character... :)

Comment: select *  from clients where replace(phone,'.','') = '123456789'; Is working fine with sample data i created. can you show us sample data / table structure.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario haha we also consider '-'

Comment: @user868766 what data type did you use for phone? mine was varchar and it return empty result.
Query `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REPLACE(phone, '.', '') LIKE ".$searchtext."` 
the value for searchtext is 123456789 it should output 123.456.789

Comment: It would be better to store phone numbers in a standardised format see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925/is-there-a-standard-for-storing-normalized-phone-numbers-in-a-database It would also help if you added phone number into title

Comment: @davidstrachan that was our mistake. since we are handling different countries with different phone formats we set the phone number as varchar data type.

Comment: @user868766 it worked i added a % symbol after the searchtext here is my query `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REPLACE(phone, '.', '') LIKE '".$searchtext."%'` how about if i want to display also values that contain '-' and '<space>' like 123-456-789 or 123 456 789

Comment: @kiel Great i just posted complete sample for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kiel

Here is the sample table & query. Please see if this can help you. Not sure about your table structure.

```
 CREATE TABLE `clients` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test`.`clients` (
`id` ,
`phone`
)
VALUES (
 '1', '123.456.789'
), (
'2', '123.456.785'
);



mysql> select * from clients where replace(phone,'.','') = '123456789'; 
+----+-------------+
| id | phone       |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 123.456.789 |
+----+-------------+
```

Hope this help !

Comment: thanks for this! now i need to replace . - and space so that i can get 123.456.789 , 123-456-789 and 123 456 789 any idea? im thinking of adding OR in my query but is there any easier way?

Comment: I did it thanks! here is my final query `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, '.', ''),'-',''),' ','') LIKE '".$searchtext."%' "` THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

```
select phone from table_name 
 where  replace (cast (phone as text) , '.','')  like '%123456789%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use MySQL's [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE REPLACE(my_column, '.', '') = '123456789';
```

But if `my_column` just contains integers, you should really change it to one of MySQL's [integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types).

Comment: Hi I did this but it was not successful this is my query:
`SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REPLACE(phone, '.', '') LIKE ".$searchtext."` where searchtext is the number im searching for.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace()` is the best function to do this :

```
Select * from TableName where Replace(ColumnName,'escaping character','replaced character')='your Search option'
```

for your case escaping character is `dot(.)`, replaced character is `''` and search option is `'123456789'`

Comment: I want to escape the # character, but i cant, when i escaping i have 0 results, with , - and black space works... but #didnot work `SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords FROM istorie WHERE     replace(replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''), '#', '') LIKE  '%$keyword%'` - 0 results and the two query was 1 - (#test, bla) and the other (test, bla) without #, if `SELECT 8 FROM istorie WHERE     replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '')) LIKE  '%$keyword%'` is giveing me only 1 results the query value(#test, bla)