# Best Practice storing phone numbers: with or without formatting?

Tags: ios, phone-number

My app pulls phone numbers from the IOS address book and then stores them in core data.  I've noticed that the IOS address book stores the data with formatting i.e. (650) 555 5555.  This causes problems as when you try to send this to an url to call or text it doesn't work.

For other phone numbers entered manually in my app, I have been storing them without formatting and formatting them only on display.

Is there a preferred approach to storing character-free vs. with characters?

Comment: It's on your choice, how you would like to store phone numbers. But I think, best way is to use one style for all numbers: typed manually and from Address Book. If you don't need to show stored number to user, obviously better to store without formatting. In other case, depends on particular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to you and the use you're going to give the numbers.

I've done this in the past and we chose to store phone numbers in with just plain numbers and display them with formatting according to the location  since most likely all the contact numbers would be from a specific country or location. That was going to be easier for a person to look at.

Also we could just use the number stored without any modification to just call or send texts because that required the phone without formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses, hyphens, spaces etc. are all part of the *presentation* of the phone number, not of the phone number itself, and that presentation depends on who you're presenting to. So, I don't think it's sensible to store the presentation information.

You might consider storing phone numbers using the ITU E.123 or [E.164](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164) standards.

Also, see [Is there a standard for phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745545/is-there-a-standard-for-phone-numbers)